# Smooth way to replace background-image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I’m quite new to jQuery and JS and been asked to write a script that will be loading `background-image` progressively - I mean that low quality image should appear immediately and when full size image is loaded should replace the small one.

I found some tips how to do something similar by layering `<img />` on top of `background-image` however in my case i have to deal with `background-image` only, so I have made this:

```
$('.img-loader').each(function(){
    var box = this;

    var smallImg = $(this).attr('style');
    var bigImg = smallImg.replace('.jpg)', 'big.jpg)');
    var imgUrl = bigImg.replace('background-image: url', '');
    var imgUrlS = imgUrl.replace(/[{()}]/g, '');
    console.log(imgUrlS);

    $('<img/>').attr('src', imgUrlS).load(function(){
        $(this).remove();
        $(box).attr('style', bigImg);
    });
})
```

The script basically does the job but in that moment when the image gets replaced there is a quite noticeable ‘shake’.

Any ideas how to make transition smoother or anyone knows what causing this 'shake'?

Edit: As suggested I'm adding a markup snipped of where script has to be applied.

```
<div class="about__section__bgimage img-loader"
style="background-image: url(<?php echo $contentBlock->imageurl ?>)"></div>
```

Comment: You aren't going to be able to animate a background image source. Could you use a pseudo-element for the high-quality image and fade that in?

Comment: Also, rather than manipulating the entire `style` attribute, which is a bit heavy-handed, I'd look at passing in the smallImg path using a custom data-attribute and applying it specifically, then building the bigImg path from that value.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you create two separate elements with the same size, overlapping each other, with position: absolute; make one of them visible with the original bg image (using opacity: 1). The second one invisible (using opacity:0)

Once the higher quality image is completely loaded, set the opacity of the original image to 0 and the new image to 1.

use a css transition on the opacity property to make the opacities change smoothly.

Comment: I was working on exactly that but ran out of time. Feel free to run with this. The only thing not working is the transition, possibly because the element is new. https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/eahcu6pL/

Comment: Thanks guys! This works way smoother than what I done. Just need to work out the transition now. Cheers.

Comment: I've used `animation` instead of `transition` - looks great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you have to use animation for this. Use  any of them according to your scenario   enjoy it !!! 
https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

Comment: Link-only answers are not considered valuable on SO.